# What is thare any special boost\std container for trees?

Tags: c++, boost, tree, std

So I want to store pairs `string-path <-> my_file_object` in such container with expected total object size 100 000.

- I need to have search by absolute path to get an object for example I could search for `a/b/c/file.h`)
- I need to be capable to list all item names in `folder` like folder `a/b/c/` contains files `file.h`, `file.cpp`, folder `bin/` and folder `bin2/`
- I need to be capable to add new `files` by absolute path, and update them.
- I need to be capable to delete `files`.

I wonder about fiew things - is there a container for such things in STL/boost? Is this implementation threadsafe for read?

Also I wonder if it is any way faster than have all my pairs inside of `std::map<string, object>` so I would have fast search, fast insert and delete, and folder files listing via [code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169320/setstring-how-to-list-not-strings-starting-with-given-string-and-ending-with)?

Comment: Without having looked at all, I would say if you want all that functionality you'll have to write your own class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What requirements do you have that rule out `std::map`? As far as I can see it will work well here:

```
typedef std::map<std::string,file_object_t> paths_t;
paths_t paths;

//I need to have search by absolute path
paths_t::iterator fileIterator = paths.find("a/b/c/file.h");
if( fileIterator  != paths.end() ) {
  ...
} 

//I need to be capable to list all item names in folder like folder a/b/c/
std::string folder = "a/b/c/";
paths_t::iterator folderBegin = paths.upper_bound(folder );
paths_t::iterator folderEnd = paths.upper_bound(folder+MAX_CHAR);
std::for_each(folderBegin,folderEnd,...);

//I need to be capable to add new files by absolute path
if( !paths.insert(paths_t::value_type("a/b/c/file.h",file)).second ) {
  //add file failed 
}

//and update them.
paths["a/b/c/file.h"].some_method_that_updates_file();

//I need to be capable to delete files
paths.erase(fileIterator);
```

Comment: I have literally non!) but guys who write STD and Boost are smart so I heped for some faster thing=)

Comment: What makes you think this is slow?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a tree-like structure, use the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/index.html).

If you want a file system abstraction (with access to the file system in question, not some snapshot in memory you seem to be describing), use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/index.html)