# Having a std::set with only file names (a, f/a, f/b, f/f/c, etc) how to list a directory by given f/?

Tags: c++, search, boost, stl, set

So we have a set of file names\urls like `file, folder/file, folder/file2, folder/file3, folder/folder2/fileN`, etc. We are given a string like `folder/`. We want to find `folder/file`, `folder/file2`,  `folder/file3`, and most intrestingly `folder/folder2/` (we do not want to list forlder2 contents just show that it exists and it can be searched). Is such thing possible via STL and Boost, and how to do it?

Ups - just found out that I already loocked for this once a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169320/setstring-how-to-list-not-strings-starting-with-given-string-and-ending-with/7169544#7169544)... but havent found correct answer yet...

Comment: Try `substr()`. A suitable data structure would be a *prefix tree* (or "trie"), but for a small number of elements that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Why are you having it in std::set? Make a custom custom class for your requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [set<string>: how to list not strings starting with given string and ending with `/`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169320/setstring-how-to-list-not-strings-starting-with-given-string-and-ending-with)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a great opportunity to use regex stuff in Boost/C++11

Something like

```
std::set<std::string> theSet;
// Get stuff into theSet somehow

const std::string searchFor= "folder/";

std::set<std::string> matchingSet;
std::for_each(std::begin(theSet), std::end(theSet),
              [&matchingSet, &searchFor] (const std::string & s)
{
    if (/* the appropriate code to do regex matching... */)
        matchingSet.insert(s); // or the match that was found instead of s
});
```

Sorry I can't provide the regex syntax... I need to study that more.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simply C++11 implementation.  This could be modified to C++03 easily.  (caveat: have not compiled or tested this).

```
std::set<std::string> urls;           // The set of values you have
std::string key_search = "folder/";   // text to search for

std::for_each(
    urls.begin(),
    urls.end(),
    [&key_search] (const std::string& value)
{
    // use std::string::find, this will only display
    // strings that match from the beginning of the 
    // stored value:
    if(0 == value.find(key_search))
        std::cout << value << "\n"; // display
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The ordered containers have a set of methods that are quite useful in finding a range of iterators: `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`. In your case, you want to use:

```
std::for_each(
    path_set.lower_bound("folder/"),
    path_set.upper_bound("folder0"), // "folder" + ('/'+1)
    ...);
```